# iTextSharp 7 PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage returns non readable data

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I'm trying to evaluate various libraries to read PDF files. One of them is iText 7, the 7.0.4 .NET version to be precise. Some files work fine, but there is at least one file i tested it with, where iText simply returns gibberish (most files work just fine).

This is my code:

```
private void PdfToText(FileInfo pdfFileInfo, FileInfo textFileInfo)
{
  var textFile = new StreamWriter(textFileInfo.FullName);
  var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFileInfo.FullName));
  var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
  for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
  {
    var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);

    string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
    textFile.Write(text);
  }
  pdfDocument.Close();
  textFile.Close();
}
```

The resulting file starts with this in hex (and goes on like this as well):

[image]

Other libraries can extract the text from this file just fine, selecting the text with Foxit Reader and then use copy paste to Notepad++ also gives me readable text.

I'm sorry, but i can't provide the PDF in question, since it contains confidential data.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Customers can share PDFs with confidential data with iText Software under NDA. If you are a customer, please contact your sales account manager. If you are not a customer, please check iText's open source license; maybe you *should* be a customer. If you are not a customer, please don't expect an answer on Stack Overflow, because you have a *very specific* problem with a *specific* PDF file, hence the solution is probably not useful for the community. Moreover, you're not providing sufficient information for anyone to solve the problem. IMHO, this question isn't eligible for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your output very often contains the sequence `EF BF BD` which in UTF-8 represents the replacement character. This often indicates character encoding conversion issues. And that's about as much as can be said without the PDF in question.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but i was on holidays. I'm sorry, but i can't provide the PDF in question, since it is confidential information we got from our client, not our own confidential information.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie as i said, i was/am evaluating various libraries for the task at hand, i was using the iText trial. There are quite a bunch of PDFs with this issue, and i thought maybe someone already knows the problem. And if so, someone else who might run into the same issue in the future, might find this and and maybe a solution to it. And of course i don't ask easy general questions, i can solve those myself, or someone else already asked them. But anyway, as things stand, iText is not usable for us.